# How do I run single line of code in a cell on Databricks?

Tags: databricks, line

In Databricks notebook I would like to run only single line of code in a cell. For example here is my cell

```
print("line 1")
print("line 2")
```

and I would like to execute only `print("line 1")`. I found how to do it in Jupyter Notebook, but not in Databricks notebook.

Answer (score 1):

Not the exact answer but might be useful for others; as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/notebooks/notebooks-code#run-selected-text) you can run only part of the cell by selecting the line and pressing `Shift` + `Control` + `Enter`.

Comment: Wow, it worked! Ty! Now we just need to change shortcut.

Comment: @user1700890 I didn't try it so I can't know for sure but doesn't that runs the whole cell if none of the text is selected? :/

Comment: I noticed one thing, it does not work well, when code is broken into multiple lines. I am trying to replicate R-studio behaviour.

Comment: Atli, it nothing is selected, it does not run at all

Comment: I'm not familiar with R-studio but what do you mean by "does not work well"?

Comment: "does not work well" I mean it does not work when multiple lines of code are selected. I mean code run through multiple line, i.e. if you consider just one line, then it is not complete.